# Possible to change the package name when generating client code

Tags: scala, swagger-editor

I am generating the client scala code for an API using the Swagger Edtior. I pasted the json then did a Generate Client/Scala. It gives me a default root package of

> io.swagger.client

I can't see any obvious way of specifying something different. Can this be done?

Answer (score 19):

Step (1): Create a file config.json and add following lines and define package names:

```
{
    "modelPackage" : "com.xyz.model",
    "apiPackage" : "com.xyz.api"
}
```

Step (2): Now, pass the above file name along with codegen command with -c option:

```
$ java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i path/swagger.json -l java -o Code -c path/config.json
```

Now, it will generate your java packages like com.xyz… instead of default one io.swagger.client…

Comment: I would have used this approach dozen of times and working perfectly for me. What error you see?

Comment: I am using python output, i still see swagger_client as initial name, so now its generating swagger_client.com.xyz.model and swagger_client.com.xyz.api. Any way to get away with swagger_client at starting?

Comment: @NitinKr maybe you need to look into "groupId" and/or "artifactId" configuration options.

Comment: This worked for me BUT this feature is broken in certain versions (e.g. 3.0.0-rc1).

Comment: anyway do do this through online codegen?

Comment: @mathtick No, you can generate in your local machine.

Answer (score 14):

Run the following command to get information about the supported configuration options

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar  config-help -l scala
```

This will give you information about supported by this generator (Scala in this example):

```
CONFIG OPTIONS

    sortParamsByRequiredFlag
        Sort method arguments to place required parameters before optional parameters. (Default: true)

    ensureUniqueParams
        Whether to ensure parameter names are unique in an operation (rename parameters that are not). (Default: true)

    modelPackage
        package for generated models

    apiPackage
        package for generated api classes
```

Next, define a config.json file with the above parameters:

```
{
   "modelPackage": "your package name",
   "apiPackage": "your package name"
}
```

And supply `config.json` as input to `swagger-codegen` using the  `-c` flag.