# Change the default package name in Swagger Editor for java project

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-editor

I have downloaded the `Swagger Editor` and run it locally from `localhost:3001`. I imported my `.yaml` file from local system. Then I clicked on `Generate Server` and I choose a `jaxrs`. When I opened a random java file I can see:

```
package io.swagger.model;
```

I have more then 30 java classes and I don't want to change it manually, because my `.yaml`maybe change in future. Is there any possibility to change it, to be for example:

```
package my.funny.package.model;
```

//Edit:

I downloaded `Swagger Editor` from this [swagger-editor](https://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#swagger-editor) and run it using code snipped from `Contribute` section. In my folder files I can't find a `.jar` file from suggested post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to change the package name when generating client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050768/possible-to-change-the-package-name-when-generating-client-code)

Comment: @Helen Could you help me to find `swagger-codegen-cli.jar`, because I can't find it anywhere in my project? I was installing it using this commands: `git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor.git -> cd swagger-editor -> npm install -> npm run build -> npm start`

From [link](https://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#swagger-editor) .

Comment: How do you generate the code? Show the command line.

Comment: I don't generate code using command line, but instead of I generated it using `localhost:3001`. @CassioMazzochiMolin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swagger Editor uses [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) (specifically, its online version at http://generator.swagger.io) to generate the client and server code. It runs the Codegen with the default settings. If you want to customize code generation, you'll need to run the Codegen directly.

#### Use Swagger Codegen CLI

Swagger Codegen has a command-line version, `swagger-codegen-cli.jar`. There are [several ways to install it](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#prerequisites) depending on your operating system. One way is to download the JAR file from Maven Central: http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/

You can run the codegen as follows:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate
     -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
     -l jaxrs
     -o Petstore-Jaxrs
     -DapiPackage=my.funny.package.model
```

Custom options, such as the package name, can be specified directly in the command line using `-D{optionName}={optionValue}` (as shown above), or using a config file as explained [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#customizing-the-generator).

To list all options a specific generator supports, use:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help -l jaxrs
```

#### Use SwaggerHub

*Disclosure: I work for the company that develops SwaggerHub.*

If you use [SwaggerHub](https://swaggerhub.com) instead of Swagger Editor to write and store your API definitions, it lets you customize Codegen options before you download the code.

[image: SwaggerHub > Edit Codegen Options]

[image: SwaggerHub > Codegen Options > jaxrs > package name]

Comment: I only download the `swagger-codegen-cli.jar` jar file and using `cmd` build it with proper parameters. Thank you for so clearly explanation!