# swagger-editor vs swagger-codegen

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

I am a newbie to swagger and I have been trying to develop api's using swagger-editor.

Swagger-codegen states that is an open source code-generator to build server stubs and client SDKs directly from a Swagger defined RESTful API.

When I work with swagger-editor I can see options :Generate server and Generate Client (I am running swagger-editor locally)

Does swagger-codegen have the same functionality as Generate server and Generate Client in swagger-editor or is there anything more to it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io) uses the online version of Swagger Codegen that is hosted at http://generator.swagger.io. There are other ways to run Swagger Codegen, for example:

- download and use the [command-line version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#prerequisites) (or build it yourself from the source code)
- use the [Docker image](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#docker)
- call the online version http://generator.swagger.io directly

The main difference is that Swagger Editor calls the Codegen with the default options. If you want to customize the output, e.g. use a [custom package name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49514341/113116) or [custom codegen templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50165530/113116), you'll need to run the Codegen yourself.